# How to generate a report as a .CIF(Catalog Interchange Format) file format?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to generate a report as a .CIF(Catalog Interchange Format) file. I searched on Google, unfortunately I couldn't get any solution.
Do we have any library available to export .cif files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the specification of the .CIF file and also if this isn't Binary based. you could just safe the file with the .cif extension.

If this is a binary file, you would need the correct classes to save the file as binary .CIF file using the binary formatter.

Otherwise it would just be like saving an xml file or even a plain .txt file.

Comment: On further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_Information_File and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_file_format it seems that .CIF is based on XML, thus you would only need to format your data objects correctly and save the file to disk.

Comment: And here is the specification you need to implement. http://www.iucr.org/resources/cif/spec/version1.1/cifsyntax